# accept strings to call functions

Tags: c++, string, function

Now before i start i know that this question might be ridiculous for you but just bear with me on this one

```
void hello()
{
    cout<<"used as a greeting or to begin a telephone conversation.";
 }
void main()
{
    #define a b()
    char b[]="hello";
    a;

}
```

So in the code above take for example that there are a few set of functions like hello (almost in thousands) and  i wish that the user enters a string(character array) which then the program uses to call a function that is already made or defined.
Like in the example above hello is typed by the user and the program then has to call the function from there.

I know the program isn't right but just bear with me.
If the question is not clear enough leave a comment and i will respond to it as soon as i can.

Comment: You may use a `std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following may help:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

void hello_world() { std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl; }
void question() { std::cout << "The answer is 42" << std::endl; }

int main()
{
    bool finish = false;
    std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> m = {
        {"hello", hello_world},
        {"question", question},
        {"exit", [&finish](){ finish = true; }},
    };

    while (!finish) {
        std::string input;

        std::cin >> input;

        auto it = m.find(input);
        if (it == m.end()) {
            std::cout << "the known input are" << std::endl;
            for (auto it : m) {
                std::cout << it.first << std::endl;
            }
        } else {
            it->second();
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can map a string to a function using `std::function` and `std::map`:

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> map;
map["hello"] = hello;
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54f40aa7c5e5ed69)

then you search what the user inputs in the `map` via `std::map::find`.

Comment: Includes: `<functional>, <string>, <map>`